# How to differentiate between a chat bot and a live chat agent on customer support live chat

Tags: chat, customer-support, chatbots, avatars, embodied-agent

I'm designing a live chat feature which uses a combination or live agents and chat bots to answer the users questions.

My question in what ways can i  help the user differentiate between a chat bot and a live chat agent on customer support live chat? 1 i'm thinking of is 1. in the name 2. the avatar image. what other ways would help?

also for the live agent, if i'm using a female avatar. hence a females vector image. should i be gender neutral? if i was what avatar image should i use??

Answer (score 1):

The way instagram does it you can change the photo before the message to something like a robot for the bot and more human looking for the agent[image]. Mentioning the name of agent and the bot would also help.